# Keycloak Authentication Flow Overrides Problem

Tags: keycloak

I'm using Keycloak 17.0.

In my client configuration under 'Authentication Flow Overrides,' I don't have anything selected. When I attempt to log in, I see the option 'Try another way,' which allows me to log in using only the email. I then receive a code and use that code to log in.

In Keycloak's settings, I allow users to have the same email.

The problem arises when a user with a duplicate email tries to log in via 'Try another way.' It's not possible, and I receive the following error in Keycloak logs:

"WARN [org.keycloak.services] (default task-100) KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: org.keycloak.models.ModelDuplicateException: Multiple users with email 'teste@mail.com' exist in Keycloak."

This behavior makes total sense, I know. However, is there any way to avoid this and send the code to the email? Of course, it should only work for the actual user who requested it.

Im expecting to keycloak sent the code to the email, regarding more than one user use the same email.